# Python copying list in a function

Tags: python

I want to overwrite the 'magicians' list by putting 'the Great' after each item.
It works if I assign the new items to a new list with pop(), making the old one empty, and by appending back to it the new names.

**code:**

```
for great in greatlist:
    mages.append(great)
```

But why doesnt simply copying it over work? The results is an empty 'mages' list.

```
mages=greatlist[:]
```

Here the whole code:

```
magicians=['feka','kuka','szuka']
#puts 'the Great' after every list element name
def make_great(mages):
    greatlist=[]
    while mages:
        uj=mages.pop()
        greatlist.append(uj + ", the Great")
#    for great in greatlist:
#        mages.append(great)
    mages=greatlist[:]
```

Comment: `['{}, the Great'.format(i) for i in magicians]`

Comment: you lack to return mages from the function an reasignt it to mages: `mages = make_great(mages)`

Comment: The last instruction does a local assignment, therefore inside the function `mages` will be the new list, but it doesn't change `magicians`, which is outside. In order to change the content of the parameter `mages` you must change its content using directly the list operators (e.g. using pop, append, item assignment `mages[i]=...`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to reassign `mages`. That is wrong in python since variables are not containers but you must think of them as labels:

```
magicians=['feka','kuka','szuka']

#puts 'the Great' after every list element name
def make_great(mages):
    greatlist=[]
    while mages:
        uj=mages.pop()
        greatlist.append(uj + ", the Great")
    return greatlist # return the resulting list

magicians = make_great(magicians) #reassign magicians labelling to the new list from function
```

Notice the scope, `greatlist` live inside the function, so once the function finished everything not global on it nor returned will be disscarded.

Comment: why do you need `return greatlist[:]`? `greatlist` is already a new list. Furthermore you are modifying the input list.

Comment: @RobertoTrani, actually yes, just the copy-paste from his code

Comment: it still continues to not overwrite the content of the original array.. this is the reason for which you need to do an assignment out of the function.

Comment: I know how it works  Roberto, thank you for pointing out anyway. I think this is the way to go instead of mutate the list inside of the function hence my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,

```
In [22]: magicians=['feka','kuka','szuka']

In [23]: def make_great(mages):
    ...:     mages = ['{}, the Great'.format(i) for i in mages]
   ....:.    return mages
    ...: 

In [25]: magicians = make_great(magicians)
#  ['feka, the Great', 'kuka, the Great', 'szuka, the Great']
```

Comment: It seems like @Chris wants to replace the list content inside the function, not outside.

Comment: @Roberto But that make difference, But I changed my code. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can also use the `list()` function

```
mages = list(greatlist)
```

That will put a copy of the `greatlist` into `mages`

Answer (score 0):

**Use this instead:-**

```
magicians=['feka','kuka','szuka']
st = "the Great"
a = [(x+" "+y) for x,y in zip(magicians,[st]*len(magicians))]
print(a)
```

Comment: Did you actually `print(a)` and look at the screen afterwards?

Comment: Okay, that fixes it, but it's still much more complicated than it needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Netwaves's comment, 'mages' is a function parameter. So it is local to the function and disappears when the function ends.

So you need to return it in the function and capture it outside of the function.

Comment: This answer would be better suitable as comment and you have enough reputation to post comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension as follows to make magicians great again !

```
magicians=['feka','kuka','szuka']
#puts 'the Great' after every list element name
def make_great(mages):
    return [each_item +" the Great" for each_item in mages]

print make_great(magicians)
```

**output:**

```
['feka the Great', 'kuka the Great', 'szuka the Great']
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to modify the input list, we can modify directly the elements:

```
magicians=['feka','kuka','szuka']

def make_great(mages):
    for i, name in enumerate(mages):
        mages[i] = name + " the Great"
    return mages
```